# No columns to parse from file after trying to process csv on flask

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I am trying to process a csv file on flask with the intention of cleaning it up. I know the actual clean up script works the way it should. However, I am new to flask and for some reason when I run my code I receive the error message:

> pandas.errors.EmptyDataError pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns
>   to parse from file

Here is the code I am using for this

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './Downloads/gmbreports'
if not os.path.exists(UPLOAD_FOLDER):
    os.makedirs(UPLOAD_FOLDER)

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = 'csv'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('You need to upload a csv file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Google My Business Discovery Report Builder</title>
    <h1>Upload GMB Discovery csv</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
from flask import send_from_directory

#once you upload the file you get cleaned up visu
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    path = UPLOAD_FOLDER + "/" + filename
    file_one = open(path)
    file_two = open(path,'w')
    for row in file_one:
        row = row.strip()
        row = row[1:-1]
        row = row.replace('""','"')
        file_two.write(row+'\n')
    file_two.close()
    file_one.close()
    discovery=pd.read_csv(path)
    return discovery
    discovery_clean=discovery.iloc[1:]
    cols=list(discovery_clean.columns[4:])
    discovery_clean[cols]=discovery_clean[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
    return discovery_clean

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have also attached a sample of the dataframe i am trying to clean 
[Sample File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ut6FY4gCHyI4LdB-aD30PDdmj78tarra)

Comment: `discovery_clean` will never be returned because of the `return discovery` before it in `uploaded_file`

Comment: It looks like your sample_file only has one column, at least, that's how it's rendered in both Excel and Google Sheets. `pd.read_csv` should attempt to infer the header from the first line by default

Comment: @C.Nivs that was typo on my part. Yes, it has one column...but the script actually cleans up the file and returns it with different columns (if I run the code on jupyter minus flask)

Comment: After downloading the file and running it in a shell with pandas I don't get separate columns. Are there commas in the data? When I try to manually clean up the results I get dimension errors